# Tips on how to setup a MOTOTRBO XPR-8300 Repeater for DMR Ham operation?

Tags: digital-modes, repeater

Goal

I am trying to setup an XPR-8300 MotoTRBO repeater ultimately with the goal of joining DMR-MARC.

Reasoning

My area does not have a repeater that's reachable on handhelds.  I got a fairly cheap XPR-8300 off a guy I know.  Not the latest and greatest gear, but should do the job.

Specific Asks ( The known unknowns ):

Where do I even get programming software for the XPR-8300?

Does anyone have a preference in what sort of duplexer I should use on this repeater?

Does anyone have any suggestions on cheap but affective antennas or antenna suppliers?

Same as above for lightning arresters and antenna supports.

And any other suggestions / warnings ( unknown unknowns )?

I've not found too much specific information on existing DMR repeaters on the google.  But if you have a link you know of, or can out google me, I'd love to read the information.

Thanks!

Comment: This is an awfully broad question, and some of its parts are highly subjective ("cheap but effective", "anyone have a preference"), and others could perfectly well be asked independently of the overall project ("antenna supports"). As it stands, if it receives answers they will likely be highly opinion-based and not be comprehensive answers. Please post your “specific asks” as separate questions and make sure they're not subjective (tip: “how do I choose a product for this purpose?” is better than “which product is best for this purpose?”

Comment: I want an overly broad answer and opinions.  That was the point of the question.  I don't want the 'how do I choose a product' that is unhelpful given the complexity of sourcing hardware and components.